# set class' private members to constructor arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

```js
class Foo {
  #one
  #two
  #three
  #four
  #five
  #six
  #seven
  #eight
  #nine
  #ten
  #eleven
  #twelve
  #thirteen
  #fourteen
  #fifteen
  #sixteen

  constructor(
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six,
    seven,
    eight,
    nine,
    ten,
    eleven,
    twelve,
    thirteen,
    fourteen,
    fifteen,
    sixteen
  ) {
    this.#one = one;
    this.#two = two;
    this.#three = three;
    this.#four = four;
    this.#five = five;
    this.#six = six;
    this.#seven = seven;
    this.#eight = eight;
    this.#nine = nine;
    this.#ten = ten;
    this.#eleven = eleven;
    this.#twelve = twelve;
    this.#thirteen = thirteen;
    this.#fourteen = fourteen;
    this.#fifteen = fifteen;
    this.#sixteen = sixteen;
  }
}
```

What's a solution to this (anti?) pattern?

Comment: Solution: Don't pass 16 arguments to a class

Comment: @0stone0 how? what if the class needs all this data from the caller. Even if I have some kind of configuration object instead of an argument list, I don't know how to iteratively set the private fields

Comment: You can iteratively set variables like using `Object.entries(contrutor_param)` in a
`for...of`

Comment: @Navitas28 for private properties?

Comment: A configuration object is much better, since with it you can update one private field (of type object) using `Object.assign`. No-one likes APIs where you have to pass 16 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 16 arguments is no fun for anyone looking to use your constructor. The configuration object idea that you raised in comments is much more interesting, certainly when you combine it with the idea to have one private property of type object that has all these properties. Then you can use `Object.assign` to have it updated with the user's preferences:

```js
class Foo {
  #options = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4
  }
  constructor(options = {}) {
    Object.assign(this.#options, options);
    console.log(this.#options);
  }
}

let foo = new Foo({three: 3000});
```